# gnome-control-center segmentation faults when launched

Tags: gnome-control-center

For some weeks now, maybe since upgrading to 21.04 (maybe earlier, not sure), gnome-control-center has been segfaulting every time I try to run it, right at start up. The gnome-control-center package version is 1:3.38.5-1ubuntu1.

Things I've tried:

- `sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade`
- `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center`
- Clearing `~/.cache/gnome-control-center` and `~/.config/gnome-control-center`
- Disabling all extensions
- Switching from Wayland to Xorg

Backtrace given by `gdb /usr/bin/gnome-control-center core` (edit: updated with more debug symbols):

```
Core was generated by `gnome-control-center'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000561583be19a1 in update_shortcut_label (label=0x5615863ad9c0, value=0x56158677b670 "<Shift><Ctrl>") at ../panels/region/cc-region-panel.c:1198
1198    ../panels/region/cc-region-panel.c: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f67e284ed40 (LWP 7635))]
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000561583be19a1 in update_shortcut_label (label=0x5615863ad9c0, value=0x56158677b670 "<Shift><Ctrl>") at ../panels/region/cc-region-panel.c:1198
#1  0x0000561583bea5a1 in update_shortcuts (self=0x5615859b43d0) at ../panels/region/cc-region-panel.c:1218
#2  setup_input_section (self=0x5615859b43d0) at ../panels/region/cc-region-panel.c:1290
#3  cc_region_panel_init (self=0x5615859b43d0) at ../panels/region/cc-region-panel.c:1689
#4  0x00007f67ef0b1f2a in g_type_create_instance () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007f67ef09aabd in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#6  0x00007f67ef09c048 in g_object_new_valist () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#7  0x00007f67ef09c57d in g_object_new () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#8  0x0000561583c880d1 in activate_panel (gicon=<optimized out>, visibility=<optimized out>, name=0x561586389160 "Language and Region", parameters=0x0, id=0x56158634ab10 "region", self=0x5615861262b0) at ../shell/cc-window.c:155
#9  set_active_panel_from_id.constprop.0 (self=0x5615861262b0, start_id=0x56158634ab10 "region", parameters=0x0, add_to_history=1, error=<optimized out>) at ../shell/cc-window.c:405
#10 0x00007f67ef08a4a4 in g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__STRINGv () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#11 0x00007f67ef0a9724 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#12 0x00007f67ef0a9893 in g_signal_emit () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#13 0x0000561583b75cf6 in row_activated_cb (listbox=<optimized out>, row=0x561586354f10, self=0x5615861ee280) at ../shell/cc-panel-list.c:592
#14 0x00007f67ef08a61e in g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__OBJECTv () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#15 0x00007f67ef0a9724 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#16 0x00007f67ef0a9893 in g_signal_emit () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#17 0x00007f67ef0a9724 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#18 0x00007f67ef0a9aa9 in g_signal_emit_by_name () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#19 0x0000561583b76681 in cc_panel_list_set_active_panel (self=0x5615861ee280, id=0x561586389180 "region") at ../shell/cc-panel-list.c:1029
#20 0x0000561583b7950d in cc_window_constructed (object=0x5615861262b0) at ../shell/cc-window.c:744
#21 0x00007f67ef09aba7 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#22 0x00007f67ef09c048 in g_object_new_valist () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#23 0x00007f67ef09c57d in g_object_new () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#24 0x0000561583b7752c in cc_window_new (application=0x5615860fd700, model=model@entry=0x561585ed05e0) at ../shell/cc-window.c:861
#25 0x0000561583b787a4 in cc_application_startup (application=0x5615860fd700) at ../shell/cc-application.c:234
#26 0x00007f67ef0a9724 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#27 0x00007f67ef0a9893 in g_signal_emit () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#28 0x00007f67ef1ae6e2 in g_application_register () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#29 0x00007f67ef1aee2e in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#30 0x00007f67ef1af1e6 in g_application_run () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#31 0x0000561583b6fc98 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at ../shell/main.c:65
```

Any pointers or ideas?

Comment: Could you install the `gnome-control-center-dbgsym` package? That will clear up the `??` lines in the backtrace.

Comment: @galexite thanks for the suggestion. See the edited question for the new backtrace, now with less `??`.

Comment: Do you have any custom Language & Region settings, such as a keyboard layout?

Comment: I do indeed, and your below answer fixed this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Fantastic! I looked at the source code listed and found that it creates that `gsettings` key mentioned.

Comment: Unable to locate package gnome-control-center-dbgsym

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try

```
$ gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
```

and then reboot, to see if that helps your problem?

Comment: did not change anything