# Login loop: Gnome keyring.SystemPrompter exited with status 1 after recursive reset of gsettings

Tags: drivers, gnome, dbus, dconf, gsettings

I was on this site looking for a solution to a segmentation fault that occurred when attempting to run `gnome-control-center`. I made the poor mistake of blindly following the solution posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356955/gnome-control-center-segmentation-faults-when-launched) without checking their technical circumstances against my own. I used the command

```
$ gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
```

and then rebooted. This caused a login loop when I attempted to re-login. There was some advice posted to try reinstalling `gnome-keyring` or uninstalling some Nvidia drivers, however, I am not aware of the unintended consequences that may arise out of these commands. System information provided below. I am on Ubuntu 20.04 on a Thinkpad X220 running DWM as my wm.

`.xinitrc` File:

```
#!/bin/sh

setxkbmap -option caps:escape
feh --bg-scale ~/Downloads/Pictures/darkforest.jpg
export AWT_TOOLKIT=MToolkit

dwmstatus 2>&1 >/dev/null &

exec dwm
```

`journalctl -xe` output:

```
Mar 12 16:03:34 bxtt dbus-daemon[841]: [session uid=1000 pid=841] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.secrets' requested by ':1.9' (uid=1000 pid=905 comm="/usr/libexec/goa-daemon " label="unconfined")
Mar 12 16:03:34 bxtt gnome-keyring-daemon[975]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/1000/keyring/control: No such file or directory
Mar 12 16:03:34 bxtt gnome-keyring-d[975]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/1000/keyring/control: No such file or directory
Mar 12 16:03:34 bxtt dbus-daemon[841]: [session uid=1000 pid=841] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.secrets'
Mar 12 16:03:34 bxtt dbus-daemon[841]: [session uid=1000 pid=841] Activating service name='org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter' requested by ':1.15' (uid=1000 pid=975 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --foreground" label="unconfined")
Mar 12 16:03:34 bxtt org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter[982]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Mar 12 16:03:34 bxtt gcr-prompter[982]: cannot open display:
Mar 12 16:03:34 bxtt dbus-daemon[841]: [session uid=1000 pid=841] Activated service 'org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter' failed: Process org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter exited with status 1
Mar 12 16:03:34 bxtt gnome-keyring-daemon[975]: couldn't create system prompt: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter exited with status 1
Mar 12 16:03:34 bxtt gnome-keyring-d[975]: couldn't create system prompt: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter exited with status 1
Mar 12 16:03:34 bxtt goa-daemon[905]: secret_password_lookup_sync() returned NULL
Mar 12 16:03:34 bxtt goa-daemon[905]: /org/gnome/OnlineAccounts/Accounts/account_1624846805_0: Setting AttentionNeeded to TRUE because EnsureCredentials() failed with: No credentials found in the keyring (goa-error-quark, 4)
```

Comment: I wonder if you're experiencing something like this: [Gnome Keyring - SystemPrompter doesn't show up](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1574322#p1574322)

Answer (score 0):

After attempting to put `dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DISPLAY` in both my `.xinitrc` and `.bashrc` with no result, I just use `Ctrl+Alt+F3` and then uninstalled `xdm` and reinstalled which fixed the issue.